# Tool or trick to require doubleclicking to launch apps from dock?

Tags: dock

Is there a way to make it so that launching an app from the dock requires a double click instead of a single click?  I find myself accidentally launching apps and then needing to force-quit them.

I'm hoping for some OS hack or third-party app.  Yes, I already have the dock hidden.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can move the dock's location and size by going to System Preferences > Dock. Rather than keeping the dock at the bottom, where the mouse needs to be often, move it to either the right or left sides of the screen.

I auto-hide the dock on the left side of the screen (I'm on a 13" MacBook Air, so my vertical space is limited too). You could also use @VxJasonxV's suggestion of removing the apps from the dock. Most of the programs I launch are via  spotlight (the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut is very useful). And the last trick I use is [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?cat=4). I bound five-finger-click to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, which makes it very easy to quit applications, but not so easy that it accidentally quits applications I didn't mean to quit.

Comment: +1 move the dock. It is much better placed on the side.

Comment: Five finger click to close... interesting idea. Definitely not the easiest thing to do, which might just be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't hide the Dock. You'll be less surprised when it pops out at you and eats your click.
2. If applications must be "force quit" when you accidentally open them, get them out of your Dock! Use a launcher like Alfred, LaunchBar, Quicksilver, or Google Quick Search Box. Or even Spotlight!

I rarely, if ever, use the mouse to open applications, much less use the dock.

Comment: 1. I'm usually programming on an 11" macbook air so vertical space is at a premium.

Comment: @peanutbutter I'd put the dock on the side if I were using an 11" Macbook Air